# Tomar datos de un JsonArray con Retrofit

Tags: java, android, json, studio

Tengo el siguiente elemento de Array devuelto con json_encode . Mi pregunta es como tomar ese array con nombre **ArrayNombre** mediante retrofit...

```
{
  "ArrayNombre": [
    {
      "idUser": "180",
      "Nombre": "Aaron",
    }
  ]
}
```

Dentro del onResponse de la consulta retrofit tomo los datos mediante

```
ArrayList mArrayList=new ArrayList<>(response.body());
```

Los datos son rellenados tomados mediante la Interface

```
   @GET("posts")
    Call<List<Posts>> getPosts();
```

No tengo problemas si el json_encode es devuelto sin un nombre de array, pero si el el array tiene un nombre como en este caso no logro tomar los datos. De que manera se tiene que ingresar al array?

Con volley lo hacia mediante

```
JSONArray json=response.optJSONArray("ArrayNombre");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un posible problema es la interfaz de retrofit:

```
@GET("posts")
Call<List<Posts>> getPosts();
```

Has indicado que esperas una lista de posts, pero el JSON es un objeto que dentro tiene el atributo ArrayNombre que es una lista:

```
{
  "ArrayNombre": [
    {
      "idUser": "180",
      "Nombre": "Aaron",
    }
  ]
}
```

Entonces debes crear algo como lo siguiente, no sé si estás utilizando GSON y tampoco he visto tu modelo de datos:

```
Class Posts {
  @Serialized("ArrayNombre")
  List<Post> list;
}

Class Post {
  @Serialized("idUser")
  String id;
  @Serialized("Nombre")
  String name;
}
```

Y cambiar la interfaz:

```
@GET("posts")
Call<Posts>> getPosts();
```